# routing omnichannel message to our own custom-made chat plugin

Tags: einstein, chat, omnichannel, einstein-chatbot

I have integrated the web bot on a community page in Salesforce and configured the appropriate `Einstein Bot` using `Dialog` and `Intent` successfully. Now, in order to receive the message from a customer within Salesforce, I probably need to set up `omnichannel`.

but what I want is, is it possible to route the incoming message from bot to our custom chat view because we already have a chat plugin so rather than using the omnichannel view we want to route the message to our custom-made window.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the liveAgent API to retrieve those bot messages

Comment: so do you mean that , if some customer sends message to Einstein bot then that message can be fetched using liveAgenet APIs?

Comment: Exactly, you can interact perfectly with the bot using the liveAgent API, retrieve and send messages to the bot is totally possible. It is exactly the approach we are using in my project and it is working perfectly.